# How do you change the default spacing unit in materialui

Tags: material-ui

I've just started using material ui and am trying to change the base spacing unit from 8 to 10px. Where in my theme do I set this?

Comment: Where did you see that `8px`?

Comment: https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/

Actually I see how to do it now, just set the spacing value when I create my theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  spacing: 4,
});

theme.spacing(2) // = 4 * 2
```

https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/